# HDMI Audio not working, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, hdmi

I recently got a TV that I'm using as a second monitor and as speakers for now, but audio doesn't want to play out of it.

I first tried installing pavucontrol, which shows HDMI as unplugged. Tried unplugging and plugging back in... No good.

Next I looked at `pacmd list-cards`, and all the HDMI options are listed as available "no" (with a few listed as unknown.)

I tried `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` but that just brought me to square one.

Any suggestions?